# Downloaded PDF file is broken

Tags: node.js, file, express, vue.js

I am trying to send pdf file contents as response in express and in the frontend, want to receive it and save as pdf again.

Here's my express code.

```
app.post('*', (req, res) => {

    ...

    fs.readFile(filePath , function (err,data){
      res.type('application/pdf')
      res.send(data)
    });
})
```

filePath is the full path of the pdf file and the file is exists.

In the frontend

```
import fileDownload from 'js-file-download'

axios.post(process.env.API_ENDPOINT)
  .then(response => {
     fileDownload(response.data, 'reports.pdf', 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8')
  })
```

Downloading works, but downloaded pdf file is broken.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps the file is getting truncated? Do the sizes match?

Comment: Size gets a little smaller

Comment: What happens if you request it directly from the browser, without using axios. Does it work? (change `post` to `get` so you can test the route directly)

Comment: I've dealt with transferring pdf before, and have found that the most reliable way to do is using an API (without relying on a external link) is to create a link that has passes a base46 encoded object like so... `el.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(b64toBlob(string, 'application/pdf'));`

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I can't change it to get for some reasons

Comment: @Daniel it's not working

Comment: right, that code alone wouldn't, but the idea is that the server sends the file encoded in base64, then in the frontend you convert it into blob, add it to a link, and use js to fake a click. It's a bit complex and I don't have drop-in code for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of the code that may work for you.

It doesn't include the base64 translation I mentioned in the comments, but it may not be necessary and will save you some work on the backend. I've found that I've had some issues when I tried without it, but I can't recall what that was about.

```js
showFile(blob){
  // It is necessary to create a new blob object with mime-type explicitly set
  // otherwise only Chrome works like it should
  var newBlob = new Blob([blob], {type: "application/pdf"})

  // IE doesn't allow using a blob object directly as link href
  // instead it is necessary to use msSaveOrOpenBlob
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
    return;
  } 

  // For other browsers: 
  // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
  const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = data;
  link.download="file.pdf";
  link.click();
  setTimeout(function(){
    // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
  , 100}
}

fetch([url to fetch], {[options setting custom http-headers]})
  .then(r => r.blob())
  .then(showFile)
```

source: https://blog.jayway.com/2017/07/13/open-pdf-downloaded-api-javascript/